# Can I open an AJAX response in a new tab using Firebug

Tags: ajax, firefox, post, xmlhttprequest, firebug

I used to be able to open AJAX responses in a new tab using Firebug

I'd right click the response, and Open in a New Tab, and it would work fine. The POST or GET data would be reposted to the same page, so I could see the response.

Since a recent Firefox update, if I Open in a New Tab, it opens the AJAX target, but without any data posted to the page.

Is there something I can do to get the old functionality back? I would LOVE to be able to view an AJAX response in a new tab, along with all posted data...

Thank you all in advance.

Here's what I can see... to get to this I click the FireBug button top right

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using Firebug? I assume you got automatically switched to the Firefox DevTools, because [Firebug is discontinued and does not work anymore in multi-process Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/). Maybe you could add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianZartner . You are probably right, this is Firefox DevTools. I click the Firebug button to get to it. Does this button now lead to the DevTools? And does this mean that opening a POST request is now impossible... what about if I downgrade to an old version of FireFox?

Comment: Yes, the button now opens the DevTools. And yes, opening a POST request is currently not possible within the DevTools, as I stated in my answer. You can get Firebug to work again by [downgrading to an old version of Firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/), though then you'll miss bug fixes and new features of new versions of Firefox and you won't know when the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Network panel in the Firefox DevTools up to Firefox 58.0 only does GET requests when you choose the option *Open in New Tab* for a request.

As mentioned in a [post in the Firebug discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/t3quNcR3D7s/cRZ3xYzRDgAJ), [bug 1220758](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220758) was filed to change this behavior to work like in Firebug.
This bug is fixed for Firefox 59.0. So, starting from that version a POST request will be done when the original request was made using POST.

Comment: Thank you for that thread. It answers all my questions. Guess I have to wait for the update of DevTools or downgrade my Firefox... I would never have updated if I knew it would break the Firebug functionality